# Data file not found error when building android OCR tesseract and hence not able to see OCR results

Tags: android-studio, dependencies, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to build tesseract ocr with android studio. my app gets build and installed when I used connected device as my mobile.It is able to capture image but ocr results doesn't display beacuse of following logcat error:

```
2020-07-25 17:52:50.839 26053-26053/com.example.tess3 I/MainActivity: Created directory 
/storage/emulated/0/TesseractSample/tessdata
2020-07-25 17:52:51.042 26053-26053/com.example.tess3 E/MainActivity: Data file not found at 
/storage/emulated/0/TesseractSample/tessdata/eng.traineddata
```

My manifest permission code is:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I am using targetsdkversion 29.
Please let me know if it is external connected related issue or do I need to download NDK also because I didn't have NDK.

Comment: You need to copy `eng.traineddata` to Data file not found at 
`/storage/emulated/0/TesseractSample/tessdata/eng.traineddata`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Tesseract Error. Data file not found at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139751/android-tesseract-error-data-file-not-found-at)